PostgreSQL: pg_settings view's "pending_restart" not showing correct value

I have seeing a strange behaviour with PostgreSQL13 pg_settings system view. I tried updating max_connections using SET command and left without a restart. But if I query from the same session or any new session the pending_restart column in pg_settings is not showing true for this parameter. However if I issue a statement like I attached in the screenshot then pending_restart column shows correctly as `true. What's this behaviour related to?

Do not post images of text when you could just show the text itself instead.
